# Convert floating point number from binary to a decimal number

Tags: math, floating-point, binary, decimal

I have to convert floating point number from binary to usable decimal number.

Of course my floating point number has been separated into bytes, so 4 bytes total.
1           2           3       4
[xxxxxxxx][xxxxxxxx][xxxxxxxx][xxxxxxxx]

These 4 bytes are already converted to decimal, so I have e.g.
1    2    3    4
[0][10][104][79]

Now Mantissa is held in three parts, two rightmost bytes (3 & 4) and in byte 2 but without the MSB bit (that one is easy to mask out, so let's assume we have a nice decimal number there as well). So three decimal numbers.

**Is there an straightforward mathematical conversion to a floating point mantissa for these three decimal numbers?**

This is along the lines: if I needed to get an integer, the formula would be
10 * 65536 + 104 * 256 + 79.

Comment: Why are you doing it by hand?

Comment: Is this an [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) floating point number, or some other format?

Comment: If it is IEEE 754, the answer is no, it is not possible to give a simple formula to convert the mantissa, because its interpretation depends on the exponent.

Comment: sfstewman: No, it is a single precision 32 bits floating point created in C on UNIX machine.

    Sign bit: 1 bit
    Exponent width: 8 bits
    Significant precision: 24 (23 explicitly stored)  
Patricia: I have the full bit set so even if it is dependent on the exponent, conversion is possible since the data is there.  
Pieter: Because I am doing it in a third party software with no methods available for such a task.

Comment: @pjercic: That's most likely a single-precision IEEE 754 floating point number, however you should really verify this, because the format is important, and neither C nor Unix, themselves, are clear enough to infer the format.  Both C and Unix exist for a variety of architectures, and a variety of floating point formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call these bytes `a`, `b`, and `c`. I assume `a` has already been masked, so it contains only the bits of the significand and none of the exponent, and that the number is IEEE-754 32-bit binary floating-point, with bytes taken with the appropriate endianness.

If the raw exponent field is 1 to 254 (thus, not 0 or 255), then the significand is:

```
1 + a*0x1p-7 + b*0x1p-15 + c*0x1p-23
```

or, equivalently:

```
(65536*a + 256*b + c) * 0x1p-23 + 1.
```

If the raw exponent field is 0, then remove the 1 from the sum (the number is subnormal or zero). If the raw exponent field is 255, then the floating-point value is infinity (if `a`, `b`, and `c` are all 0) or a NaN (otherwise).

Comment: This answer presumes an IEEE 754 single-precision float.

Comment: Sorry, just to ask 0x1p-23 is the scaling factor and it means 1 * 2 ^ -23 which is 0.00000011920928955078125?
Am I right?

Comment: @pjercic: Yes. Hexadecimal floating-point numerals are part of C. They have the form “0x”, some hexadecimal digits optionally including a period, “p”, and a decimal exponent optionally including a sign. The exponent is a power of two. Hexadecimal numerals are a good way to express binary floating-point values precisely.

Comment: Sorry, I actually deleted the comment since the error was in using on the server side an ntohl() on a float number, which corrupts it heavily. Mark my words, ntohl() is an enemy of the float. Thank you for the answer, I got it working now.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot be of much help, since it has been a while since I did conversions, but I hope you find [this tutorial](http://kipirvine.com/asm/workbook/floating_tut.htm) useful.

Comment: Thanks, I followed this one.